# Haar measure is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure?

Tags: lie-groups, lebesgue-measure, haar-measure, radon-nikodym

Is the Haar measure on a real Lie group absolutely continuous with respect to a Lebesgue measure?

I just got introduced to the Haar measure and Lie groups. I know measure theory, but my background in group theory and differential geometry is limited. I know that the statement is true for the Haar measure on the translation group and the orthogonal group. In the end, I am interested in the Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym decomposition of such a Haar measure.

Comment: Lebesgue measure IS Haar measure.

Comment: What is your definition of "a Lebesgue measure" in this setting?

Comment: @NateEldredge By Lebesgue measure I mean a Haar measure on the translation group R^n.

Comment: @user658409 According to what I read a Lebesgue measure is a Haar measure for the translation group R^n. I am interested about Haar measures on any LC real Lie group. Is there an example which is not absolutely continuous wrt the Lebesgue measure on R^n?

Comment: I still don't understand the question.  To talk about one measure being absolutely continuous with respect to another, they both need to be defined on the same space.  If $G$ is an arbitrary real Lie group, you would need to define "Lebesgue measure on $G$", not just on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Agreed. You could represent $G$ as an open submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and then take the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I don't think so.  For instance, no compact Lie group can be an open submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  I think that orangeskid's answer is the most relevant result, just keeping in mind that it still doesn't define a unique "Lebesgue measure" on the entire group $G$.  But the original question really wasn't well-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some observations:

A Lie group is always locally compact.

In every coordinate system the (a) Haar measure will be of form 
$f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) dx_1\ldots dx_n$, where $f$ is a smooth positive function. So we can say that it is equivalent to the Lebesgue measure (although the Lebesgue measure depends on the coordinate system, while the Haar measure does not).

We can get an explicit form for the Haar measure in a coordinate system around say $e$. It is helpful to keep in mind the Haar measure for the group $(\mathbb{R}^{\times}, \cdot)$ which is $\frac{d x}{|x|}$. Now, for the coordinate system around $e$, let $f(0,0, \ldots, 0)=1$, then $f(x)=f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)=\frac{1}{|J(L_{x})|}$, where $L_x$ is the left multiplication in the Lie group by the element corresponding to $x$, and the Jacobian is considered in the given coordinate system at the point $(0,0,\ldots, 0)$. All this is to make the measure invariant under all the left multiplications.

Comment: Thanks for the observations @orangeskid! I will edit out the "locally compact" in my question. This would mean that the answer to the question is "yes", with $f$ as the Radon-Nikodym derivative of the Haar measure w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure (as I understand it). Could you give me a reference for your second statement?

Comment: @Idontgetit: No worries!  The statement  should be in many basic books on Lie groups, can't pinpoint one at the moment.  I added some detail regarding the concrete form of $f$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this solves my question!